# How to italic a word in sentence on Android studio?

Tags: java, android, string, android-studio, arraylist

I'm new at developing an Android app. I wanted to make some of the words into italic, but it's not working properly.
Can you tell me is it possible to make a word in sentence into italic? If it's possible tell me how to make it italic?

I made a glosarium with listview, the sentence I made it on array list like this

```
a.add("Acuminatus"+"Type of leaf");
```

How to italic the word "Acuminatus" I have tried to add like

```
"\030 Acuminatus"
```

Or

```
"<i>Acumunatus</i>"
```

But its still not working

More the code

```
Private List<String> populateA() {
List<String> a=new ArrayList<String>();

a.add("Acuminatus"+"\n \n Type of leaf");
..... 
Return a;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the below method where you are going to display:

```
public static Spanned fromHtml(String html) {
        Spanned result;
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            result = Html.fromHtml(html, FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY);
        } else {
            result = Html.fromHtml(html);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Calling Like:

```
textview.setText(fromHtml("<i>Acumunatus</i> Type of leaf"))
```

Comment: It would be better to directly create a Spanned string. Creating an artificial Html and then converting it, is a lot of overhead.

Comment: Yes I know, but the strings are dynamic and so, index finding is difficult for him. So added the simple solution here

Comment: Can you guide me how to implement it on my ArrayList?

Comment: you can collect each item from arrayList and pass to the fromHtml() method. as `textview.setText(fromHtml(a[i]))`

Comment: Also another possible idea could be to change the font of what your using if it suits your purposes.

Comment: Thanks all for you, It worked. I used it on my adapter

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`SpannableString`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableString) with a Span of type [`StyleSpan`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/StyleSpan) .. Call [`setSpan()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableString#setSpan(java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int,%20int)) that takes the indices of the text that you want to style

```
SpannableString output = new SpannableString("Acuminatus" + " Type of leaf");
output.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.ITALIC), 0, 11, 0);
textview.setText(output);
```